# Need guidance on how to obtaining ADAL access_token in Ember SPA via JSLL

Tags: ember.js, adal

I have and Ember SPA that uses JSLL to interactively log a user in and then make cross-domain calls to our dependent services. I'm working on a VSTS Release definition that will deploy the app then invoke a particular 'health page' that executes synthetic transactions to the dependent services and reports.

What I need guidance on is the proper way to bypass the interactive login but still be able to acquire heedlessly the access_token(s) needed for the ajax calls to the dependent services.

VSTS provides a SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN build variable that would make secrets management very simple but I don't think it is well suited for what I'm trying to do.

The best way I can figure is to create a service principle in AAD, provision that account with my dependent services and programmatically login to acquire the token then just use that token for the Bearer token in the Authorization header.

Is there any better approach?

If that is the recommended approach can someone point me to the JSLL/ADAL API that would accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this [code sample](https://github.com/matvelloso/emberjs-simpleauth-adal-aad) to integrate Azure AD with Ember framework. After you download and run the project, you may find the error about `container.lookup is not a function` since the reference to Ember is the latest version.

To make the code sample work, you can replace the Ember reference using the version `2.0.0-beta.3` like below:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/2.0.0-beta.3/ember-template-compiler.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/2.0.0-beta.3/ember.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I don't think I was clear.  My issue is not how to integrate ADAL into my app. That work is done and completely functional.  My question was about how to leverage the SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN property provided by VSTS build process to bypass the UI login.

After further investigation I think my very premise is not valid as that is not an appropriate use of that token.  I will pursue other solutions. Thanks for trying.

Comment: The `SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN` is used to access the Visual Studio Team Services REST API. It is not intend to authenticate for the SPA application. If you want to protect the SPA using Azure AD, the app quires the users to enter their credential to authenticate.